# After creating and adding an ssh key into the keychain I am not seeing it when I call the command `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain`

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, keychain, ssh

Following [GitHub's guide for setting up ssh keys and adding it to an agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) I created a new ed25519 key.

However, after trying to add it per the instructions I am unable to see that my key has been loaded in.

```
➜ ssh-add --apple-load-keychain                                 
Identity added: /Users/first.last/.ssh/id_ed25519 (for GitLab)
Identity added: /Users/first.last/.ssh/id_rsa (first.last@VULF8080.company.cnb)
```

#### Steps I took:

Created key with github email:
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my_github_email@email.com"`
For the prompt:
`> Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/YOU/.ssh/id_ALGORITHM: [Press enter]`
Which I entered as: `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_username`

Created `.ssh/config`
`touch ~/.ssh/config`

Which I populated as recommended:

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_username
```

I then tried to add it to the keychain.

`ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_username`